# Create TextViews with equal width in a row

Tags: android

I am trying to create a layout with three textviews beside each other. The textviews are of different length.

All I want to do is to arrange them so that they always have equal layout_width irrespective of the length of their text.

Approaches I tried:

1) I tried using linear_layout and setting the weight of textviews to be 1 but that does not do it since it applies only for the remaining width after all textViews are positioned.

2) I also tried using table layout and stretching all the columns by using stretchColumns="*". but that also allocates the required width to the length of the texts and only then does it stretch the columns.

3) This is a hack but this is not working either. I tried to have a linear layout inside a relative layout with three textviews to have no text but force them to be of equal widths by setting their weights. This works but then I want my next views which are in the relative layout to align themselves to the right and left edges of the views within the linear layout. But this does not work. Here is my layout that I used for this.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <!-- This is a hack to have all three textviews in a row to obtain equal width -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_ref1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_ref2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_ref3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My ghghhfghjjghjkkhgfhfghfjhjh"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_ref1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Text Text Text"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_ref1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Med"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_ref1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Long Text wtwy yu hjsyi"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Please let me know what I might be doing wrong or how I can force my textviews in a row to have equal widths.

Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Setting layout_width to "fill_parent" and layout_weight to "1" for all your TextEdits forces them to have equal width

Comment: That does not work. I tried it. It gives more width to the text which is longer than the other texts.

Comment: if layout_width is "wrap_content", yes; if it is "fill_parent" - no. try it

Comment: Ahh my bad. Yes it works. And even the textviews in the linearlayout within the relativelayout in my layout code also does the trick So it works either with fill_parent or 0dp for all textviews also. It may also work if we set the width of all the textviews to be same. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks.  It Works..!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `max width` attribute of properties. Set it same for all textviews means 20 or 30dip

Comment: Well I cannot always say that the textviews will be of that length. Another problem that we will face using this approach is when supporting multiple screen densities, orientations and screen sizes. I don't want to create a separate layout file for every screen factor and set different max widths for each of those views. I would rather use one layout and make it work for all cases. Thank you for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

for the root layout then check and modify the above code as you are repeating the textView after the LinearLayout is closed that is not necessary as I think.

Comment: The relative layout is not my root layout. So I do the namespace declaration in my root layout. And the linear layout is closed as it should be closed. The textviews within that layout are just a hack and if it works I will set their height to 0dp.

Comment: Why you have used three textViews just after closing the linearlayout . they are effecting the layout of the TextViews in LinearLayout. just remove them and check it will work fine else arrange them properly.

Comment: No, thats not right. They textviews outside the linear layout are not affecting the layout of the textviews in the linear layout. And they should not do so and they are not doing so. I have tested my code.

Comment: one more thing: set the layout_below property for lower textViews with respect to the above linearLayout instead of tv_ref1. **android:layout_below="@id/linear01"** . Now adjust the lower TextViews.Try this.

Answer (score 0):

get the maximum width among all the textviews and set that width to all the textviews

```
 @Override
        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            // System.out.println("...111Height..."+mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

            width1 = textView1.getWidth();
    width2 = textView2.getWidth();
    width3 = textView3.getWidth();


    //get maximum width among all width
     int[] nums={width1 ,width2 ,width3};  
     Arrays.sort(nums);  
    int max =   nums[nums.length-1];

    //set this maximum value to all the textviews

    textView1.setWidth(max);
    textView2.setWidth(max);
    textView3.setWidth(max);

    }
```