# Create TextViews with same width in TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tablelayout, android-layout-weight

I'm facing a problem: I'd like to create a grid of icons for my main screen and so I'm using 4 `TableRows` and 3 `TextViews` in each.
The `TextViews` are made of an icon and a text, the text is of different length.

I don't know what to write in the `xml` file to make all those `TextViews` the same width in a row.
I displayed their size in `logcat` so I'm sure they're not of the same width ;)

I've tried [`m1shk4`'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6450483/3410584), but that doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/nearby"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="goToArticles"
                android:text="All Nearby" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/supermarket"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="goToMap"
                android:text="Supermarkets" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/pharmacy"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Pharmacy" />

    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/fastfood"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Fastfood" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/departmentstores"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="displaySizes"
                android:text="Department Stores" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/petrol"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Petrol Stations" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/electronics"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Electronics" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/diy"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="DIY Stores" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/banking"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Banks" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/fashion"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Fashion &amp; Clothing" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/autoparts"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Auto Service" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/more"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="All Categories" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Any idea? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`TableRow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) represents a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout`, the [weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) attribute should be used with `layout_width="0dp"` for the child views. So in order to make each `TextView` in the `TableRow` be same width replace

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

with

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

for every `TextView` in a row.